# barplot color by values in R

Tags: r

suppose I have a barplot in R:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-rnorm(10)
barplot(x)
```

what I wanted is to fill the bar with blue if `x<=0` and red otherwise. I have been trying `barplot` and `ggplot2`(which I would prefer if possible), but haven't found a better solution yet. If the filled colors can change gradually from blue (min) to red (max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with ggplot:

```
ggplot(data.frame(Index = 1:length(x), value = x), aes(Index, value, fill = value >= 0)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]